# Is x considered one consonant or two?

Tags: phonetics

We know that letter x is pronounced "cs" ("ks") i.e. as two consonants. But it is still one letter. When it stands between two vowels, is the first syllable considered open or close?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Closed.
As X stands for CS, an X between two vowels means that there are two consonants between them and therefore the preceding syllable is always heavy/long.

Sydney Allen in *Vox Latina* mentions this indirectly.
In addition to pointing out that X is CS, he mentions that this leads to a case of hidden quantity, and earlier mentions that hidden quantity is a term for the vowel length in closed syllables.